# Skipping a py.test fixture from command line

Tags: python, fixtures, pytest

given that this is my test code:

```
# conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def fixA(request)
   pass

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def fixB(request)
   pass

# test_my.py
pytestmark = pytest.mark.usefixtures("fixA")

def test_something():
   pass
```

I want to be able to use `fixB()` insted of `fixA()`, using `fixB()` is easy enough, I could add pytest.ini like this:

```
[pytest]
usefixtures=fixB
```

but I could figure out how can I disable `fixA`, from the commandline of from the configuration.
is my use case is so far fetched ?

(the actual reason, I want to keep `fixA` working in our CI system, but for day to day work, I need people to be able to disable it on their desk)

Comment: Thank for the edit, Mohsen

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way, (after fighting it in the debugger, py.test documentation isn't that clear regarding how fixtures are being selected)

Added this into the conftest.py:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    for fixture in item.config.getini('ignorefixtures'):
        del item._fixtureinfo.name2fixturedefs[fixture]
        item._fixtureinfo.names_closure.remove(fixture)

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini('ignorefixtures', 'fixtures to ignore', 'linelist')
```

and then I could put this in pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
usefixtures=fixB
ignorefixtures=fixA
```

I would be nice to those kind of things also in the command line...

Comment: You could easily add a command line option instead by using `parser.addoption` instead of `parser.addini`.

Comment: I was thinking both options are valid, but I wanted to contribute back to py.test, what do you think, it better as part of the mark plugin ? Or a plugin of it's own ?

Comment: IMO a plugin would be better, but you can ask in the mailing list to see what others have to say.  :)